Cannot knit pdf from R markdown containing flextable
Here is my R markdown document :
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
```

```{r}
ft <- flextable(head(airquality))
ft <- autofit(ft)
theme_vader(ft)
```

When I try to knit it to produce a pdf I got the following error :

Sorry, but C:\Users******\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.

It also says to check the pdflatex.log file and here is what it says:
> 2024-04-22 14:28:28,136+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (34480)
> started by Rterm in directory
> C:\Users\***\manuscript with command line:
> C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
> -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode test.tex 2024-04-22 14:28:28,137+0200 INFO  pdflatex - running on Windows 10.0.22631
> 2024-04-22 14:28:28,140+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX
> 4.19.0 (1.40.26) (MiKTeX 24.3.31) 2024-04-22 14:28:28,144+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands 2024-04-22 14:28:28,438+0200
> FATAL pdflatex.core - GUI framework cannot be initialized. 2024-04-22
> 14:28:28,438+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data:  2024-04-22
> 14:28:28,438+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source:
> Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp:126 2024-04-22 14:28:28,438+0200
> FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized. 2024-04-22
> 14:28:28,438+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info:  2024-04-22 14:28:28,438+0200
> FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp 2024-04-22
> 14:28:28,438+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 126 2024-04-22
> 14:28:28,440+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (34480) finishes with
> exit code 1

The flextable version is 0.9.5. The R version is 4.2.2. The MikTex version is 4.19.0.
I tried previous flextable version (version 0.6.6) and I also updated Miktex.
Note also that I am able to produce pdf document from .tex files using Miktex.
I am also able to knit the R markdown to word or html documents.

Using TeXlive instead of MikTeX, the code runs without problems. It appears to me that the problem is caused by missing packages that need to be installed. Did you check the answers here?

I agree with Lukas; make sure your MixTek and related packages are installed and up to date.

Thank you. Indeed, I followed the instructions in the answers given in your link and it is working now. I just had to change from "Ask me" to "Always" in the MikTex console setting about when to install package when missing. I guess my post should be deleted as it is kind of a duplicate of the linked question?
